# Solucionar error Couldn't execute 'show events' 15777

Tags: mysql, bash

Después de pasar días buscando una solución, aprovecho mi oportunidad aquí. Tengo un servidor MySQL que intento hacer una copia de seguridad con el siguiente comando:

```
mysqldump -p --all-databases --events --single-transaction -u root > root/mysqldump.sql
```

y obtengo esta respuesta al ejecutarlo:

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `EVENTS`': Cannot proceed because system tables used by Event Scheduler were found damaged at server start (1577)
```

¿podrian darme una mano por favor?

Gracias

Comment: Hola Edward,  bienvenido. ¿Te refieres a que necesitas copiar una tabla dañada con mysqldump? El mensaje de error indica que la que las tablas utilizadas por el Administrador de eventos están dañadas en tu servidor de origen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta respuesta de digz6666 y la propia pregunta a la que responde indican cómo solucionar el error: https://serverfault.com/questions/100685/cannot-proceed-because-system-tables-used-by-event-scheduler-were-found-damaged

Te la traduzco a continuación:

Intenta ejecutar estos comandos y despues renicia mysql en tu servidor:

```
mysqlcheck -u [username] -p --all-databases --check-upgrade --auto-repair

mysql_upgrade -u [username] -p
```

Si el problema continúa, borra la tabla event y créala de nuevo. Luego reinicia:

```
DROP TABLE event;
```

Encuentra la definición de la tabla event de mysql_system_tables.sql file. 
En el servidor de digz6666 tenía esta ubicación (es posible que la tengas en el mismo sitio en una ubicación diferente en función de tu sistema): `/usr/local/share/mysql/mysql_system_tables.sql`

Definición de la tabla event en Mysql 5.1:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `event`;
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `db` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` char(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `body` longblob NOT NULL,
  `definer` char(77) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `execute_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `interval_value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `interval_field` enum('YEAR','QUARTER','MONTH','DAY','HOUR','MINUTE','WEEK','SECOND','MICROSECOND','YEAR_MONTH','DAY_HOUR','DAY_MINUTE','DAY_SECOND','HOUR_MINUTE','HOUR_SECOND','MINUTE_SECOND','DAY_MICROSECOND','HOUR_MICROSECOND','MINUTE_MICROSECOND','SECOND_MICROSECOND') DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `last_executed` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `starts` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ends` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('ENABLED','DISABLED','SLAVESIDE_DISABLED') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ENABLED',
  `on_completion` enum('DROP','PRESERVE') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'DROP',
  `sql_mode` set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH') NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment` char(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `originator` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_zone` char(64) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM',
  `character_set_client` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `collation_connection` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `db_collation` char(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `body_utf8` longblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db`,`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Events';
```